# How to get app to run on iPod 2nd gen

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently trying to test my app on my 2nd generation iPod Touch running IOS 4.1 in the latest version of xCode, and even though in my organizer, under devices, my iPod has the green dot next to it, when I run the app to my device, it says "build succeeded", but nothing runs on my iPod. I have specified in xCode to run on this device, set up code signing correctly and in architectures I specified armv6 and the base SDK is 5.0. All help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: turn off your phone and turn it on again, restart Xcode. and then try once again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, there are three things stopping new projects from working on 2nd-gen iPod touches.

- The deployment target should be set low enough to support the version of iOS the iPod touch is running.
- Architectures in the build settings should include `armv6`.
- The `Info.plist` file should not include `armv7` as a required device capability.

Since Xcode won't attempt to install the application on the device if the first is the problem, and you've already fixed the second, your problem is probably the third.

Comment: What does the console log tell you?

Comment: iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.  At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6 (-19033)

Comment: Are you certain you included armv6 in Architectures in your build settings?  There are multiple levels of build settings, are you sure you set it at the correct level?

Comment: I set armv6 to project and targets.

Comment: Make a copy of your project, remove all of your code and resources, leaving just a bare-bones app delegate, then put it somewhere where people can download it to take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Deployment Target is the problem then.  The Deployment Target should be 4.0 or 4.1, and your plist should remove all references to armv7.

Comment: Base SDK is not the problem.  You're thinking of the deployment target.

Comment: Of course.  Small name mixup on my part.  +1 for your answer.

Comment: What about your target up in the top left corner of Xcode?  Are you actually installing on your iPod, or to a sim?